# Difference between rate of elimination and clearance?

Tags: pharmacology, pharmacokinetics

I honesty don't get the difference. I need a simple explanation so that I can grasp it. 
Rate of elimination is

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). For ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions, you are **required** to show your attempt to answer the question and to use the "homework" tag. (Note that "homework" can apply to questions even if they were not assigned as homework.) ——— Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

Clearance is a measure of the *volume* of plasma from which something is removed, per unit time. For instance, it could be 2 mL/min, meaning that every minute, a two-milliliter of drug plasma is cleared. In other words, it is the rate of drug elimination divided by the plasma concentration.

Remember that the elimination rate is in units of inverse time, so dividing it by inverse volume gets you volume over time, which is the standard dimensionality of clearance.

Comment: Thank you! It finally clicked.